# (Py)Qt: problem with image downloading

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, image-loading

guys
I want to display some images with their captions in `QTextEdit`. I have a dictionary with captions and corresponding URLs. The problem is when I post a request  with `QNetworkAccessManager` and wait for a signal `finished(QNetworkReply*)`, I get reply with image only. How can I determine a corresponding caption this image was requested for?

```
def _init_(self)
    manager = QNetworkAccessManager(self);
    self.connect(manager, SIGNAL("finished(QNetworkReply*)"), self.add_record)
    for record in dict:
        manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(status['caption'])))

def add_record(self, reply):
    img = QImage()
    img.loadFromData(reply.readAll())
    self.textEdit.textCursor().insertImage(img)
    #I don't know at this point for which caption
    #I've received this image
    #self.textEdit.append(record['text'] + '\n');
```

Are there any design patterns for this problem? I would appreciate any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a recent Qt version, the [`QNetworkReply::request()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qnetworkreply.html#request) will give you a pointer to the `QNetworkRequest` that triggered this reply.

So you can access the information you're after with [`QNetworkRequest::url()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qnetworkrequest.html#url).

Comment: And using url I can determine caption for it in my dict. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is a problem. I may store the same url's in the dict, thats why multiple captions will be displayed for one image

Comment: It's possible to attach originating object to the request by `setOriginatingObject(QObject)`, but how can cast long or str to QObject? Why does it dont work to `setOriginatingObject(QString)`?

Comment: @nikagra: this question requested to get the caption from the request. I believe you got that. Now you have a different question - so open a new question.